# Problems with Delegate Pattern on Android

Tags: android

I am pretty new on Android and I don't know how to do some things yet. My App has an activity which in the `onCreate` function I need to get some data asynchronous from a remote server and process it. I have a different class, a service, that retrieve the data and make the work with it. I also want to inform to the user of the progress of the work, so I am implementing the delegate Pattern.

So, my Activity looks like:

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  UpdateLibraryDelegate{

        ....

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ....

       UpdateLibraryTask updateLibraryTask = new UpdateLibraryTask();
       updateLibraryTask.setUpdateLibrarayDelegate(this);
       updateLibraryTask.execute();

   }

   private class UpdateLibraryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private UpdateLibraryDelegate updateLibraryDelegate;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        myService.setUpdateLibraryDelegate(updateLibraryDelegate);
        myService.updateLibrary();
        return null;
    }

    public void setUpdateLibrarayDelegate(UpdateLibraryDelegate updateLibraryDelegate){
        this.updateLibraryDelegate = updateLibraryDelegate;
    }

}

/**DELEGATION METHODS**/
@Override
public void startDownloadingLibrary() {         
...
}
@Override
public void endDownloadingLibrary() {           
...
}
@Override
public void processingLibrary(final int progress) {  
}
```

And my Service has something like this:

```
 public void updateLibrary(){
    ...
    if(updateLibraryDelegate!=null){
         updateLibraryDelegate.startDownloadingLibrary();   
     }
    get(library_client, url, null, library_response_handler);
 }
 public JsonHttpResponseHandler library_response_handler = new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
  @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject)
    {
        if(updateLibraryDelegate!=null){
            updateLibraryDelegate.endDownloadingLibrary();
        }
            for(...){
              //PROCESSING DATA
              updateLibraryDelegate.processingLibrary(process);
             }
    }
 }
```

With all this code in place, it seems to work fine, the delegate function get called when they should. The problem comes when I try to show anything on the UI. If I try this:

```
  @Override
  public void startDownloadingLibrary() { 
       if(progressDialog==null){
             progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
       }

        progressDialog.setProgress(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Stories, This may take a while...");

        progressDialog.show();
 }
```

I get an exception:

```
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-23 14:08:00.850: E/AndroidRuntime(11336):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
```

I found that this was because I was running that method on a thread that wasn't the UI Thread, and the solution was this:

```
    public void startDownloadingLibrary() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            if(progressDialog==null){
                                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
                            }

                               progressDialog.setProgress(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                               progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Stories, This may take a while...");

                            progressDialog.show();

                    }

                });
            }
        }.start();
}
```

But this doesn't work as I expected, although the delegate functions are getting called right, the code inside the `run` method it's not executed until the processing of the data is done.

What is the correct way to inform the user about the progress of an async process?

Is there any way to show a Dialog on my delegate function without using the `runOnUiThread` function?

I would appreciate any help...

Thanks!

Comment: why do u create another thread in startDownloading, start with HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread...

Answer (score 1):

You should probably implement the onPreExecute onProgressUpdate and the onPostExecute of the asyncTask.
So you can start showing the dialog before the task start, call publishProgress to show the progress, and close the dialog when finished.

For more information check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Hopefully that will help you.